# Can we create a POD from two existing Yamls each having their own container?

Tags: kubernetes

My project have 2 Yamls to create which create 2 PODS each.
Can we create a single POD with these yamls, without merging the yamls,  with 2 containers ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear please elaborate. Always refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to merge the `containers` definition in the same file and in the same `containers` block, then no you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you run multiple containers inside the single pod. In single YAML manifest, you can add your both containers spec and run it.

however, you cannot without merging YAML you can not run multiple containers inside one pod.

for single file example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mc1
  spec:
    volumes:
    - name: html
      emptyDir: {}
    containers:
    - name: 1st
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - name: html
        mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
    - name: 2nd
      image: debian
      volumeMounts:
      - name: html
        mountPath: /html
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args:
        - while true; do
            date >> /html/index.html;
            sleep 1;
          done
```

more details you can also refer official document : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/